# How can I open tabs in in-app browsers using javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, webview, inappbrowser

My website needs to open a new tab when user clicks on a certain button, without affecting the current tab.

It does that by running `window.open`.

However, I noticed it might not work in Facebook in-app browser.

Can someone please confirm that Facebook in-app browser does not support open new tabs using `window.open`? And maybe have a workaround for opening new tab? Thanks!

Comment: This in-app browser is basically just a webview component, and those can be configured whether to allow popups or not. I don’t know about the FB in-app browser for sure, but a bit of research finds source that suggest, that indeed _all_ popups might be blocked (https://www.kopf.com.br/kaplof/how-to-turn-off-the-facebook-in-app-browser/)

Comment: What possible workarounds could be, depends on what exactly you need to achieve. If you just need to link to a 3rd-party site, maybe a link with `target="_blank"` might work (not sure, it might be treated the same as a popup.) If you need to show some info from your own site, maybe a modal will do the trick, perhaps with an iframe (if those are supported.)